# 2d procedurally generation of hexagons using the tile-map grid?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I've been following some [guides](https://gamedevacademy.org/procedural-2d-maps-unity-tutorial/) and making a 2d procedurally generated map in unity which has worked so far but

1. I want to make it more efficient, the main method I'm generating the tiles is using a prefab so it ends up creating 100s of objects in the hierarchy and
2. I want to use hexagons, I've looked at [this](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/) and I think I know how much to space them out but I need help figuring out how to make the saw pattern or just connecting them in general.

While I've been struggling with this I feel like using the built in tile-map would solve this with it's grid. I'm also pretty new to unity and programming so idk if the answer is really obvious or not, also new to stack-overflow so hopefully I formatted this right.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Map : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BiomePreset[] biomes;
    public GameObject tilePrefab;

    [Header("Dimensions")]
    public int width = 50;
    public int height = 50;
    public float scale = 1.0f;
    public Vector2 offset;

    [Header("Height Map")]
    public Wave[] heightWaves;
    public float[,] heightMap;

    [Header("Moisture Map")]
    public Wave[] moistureWaves;
    public float[,] moistureMap;

    [Header("Heat Map")]
    public Wave[] heatWaves;
    public float[,] heatMap;

    void GenerateMap()
    {
        heightMap = NoiseGenerator.Generate(width, height, scale, heightWaves, offset);

        moistureMap = NoiseGenerator.Generate(width, height, scale, moistureWaves, offset);

        heatMap = NoiseGenerator.Generate(width, height, scale, heatWaves, offset);

        for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
            {
                GameObject tile = Instantiate(tilePrefab, new Vector3(x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                tile.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = GetBiome(heightMap[x, y], moistureMap[x, y], heatMap[x, y]).GetTileSprite();
            }
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        GenerateMap();
    }

    BiomePreset GetBiome (float height, float moisture, float heat)
    {
        BiomePreset biomeToReturn = null;

        List<BiomeTempData> biomeTemp = new List<BiomeTempData>();

        foreach(BiomePreset biome in biomes)
        {
            if(biome.MatchCondition(height, moisture, heat))
            {
                biomeTemp.Add(new BiomeTempData(biome));
            }
        }

        float curVal = 0.0f;

        foreach(BiomeTempData biome in biomeTemp)
        {
            if(biomeToReturn == null)
            {
                biomeToReturn = biome.biome;
                curVal = biome.GetDiffValue(height, moisture, heat);
            }
            else
            {
                if(biome.GetDiffValue(height, moisture, heat) < curVal)
                {
                    biomeToReturn = biome.biome;
                    curVal = biome.GetDiffValue(height, moisture, heat);
                }
            }
        }

        if(biomeToReturn == null)
        {
            biomeToReturn = biomes[0];
        }

        return biomeToReturn;
    }
}

public class BiomeTempData
{
    public BiomePreset biome;

    public BiomeTempData (BiomePreset preset)
    {
        biome = preset;
    }

    public float GetDiffValue (float height, float moisture, float heat)
    {
        return (height - biome.minHeight) + (moisture - biome.minMoisture) + (heat - biome.minHeat);
    }
}
```

[here's what it looks like rn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYLe3.png)

I looked online for help, also tried editing some of the code to see if I could fix it myself which did **NOT** work well.